# REST service returning wrong content-type if file created has its header set to some value in iOS objective C

Tags: httpresponse

In iOS I am using AFNetworking for calling the web-services. Here I am getting the error: "unacceptable content type: application/excel". After a lot of struggle I came to know that it is the server team problem. I have a question regarding this:

Before returning the response of service call to the app, notification is being sent and at the same time the notification information(text, time, etc) is logged in notification.xls file on the server where the header is set for the file like below,

```
function calledWhenServiceCalled(){
someJsonArray; //generate some json array
saveNotification();    
return someJsonArray;
}

function saveNotification(){
//some functionality
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
//save the file to .csv
}
```

If I comment out the 'header('Content-Type: application/excel');' line above then the service call does not return any error and returns proper json response. But if the line is retained then I get unacceptable content type error(application/excel) from the server.

Please let me know why is the content type set for the file header is being sent as  unaaceptable content-header for service response? There is no connection between the file created and service response right?? I am not getting what the problem is.. Please help... Let me know If I have not made myself clear...

Comment: Try adding multiple content type in AFURLResponseSerialization     self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", @"application/excel", nil];